# What is keyboard shortcut to close Qt Creator F1 panel?

Tags: qt-creator

Press `F1` when editing code and get a context help panel. What is the keyboard shortcut for closing the context help panel?

[image]

The button that collapses the context help panel is roughly 4x4mm -- a tiny click target. I cannot find a keyboard shortcut for closing the context help in Qt documentation.

Comment: If I hit `ESC` enough times, the context help panel eventually closes, but I use those other panels that are closed when I hit `ESC`. I would like to just close the context help panel.

Comment: Doesn't look like there currently is a "command" registered for that button, so it is not possible to assign a shortcut to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close just the Help pane after pressing F1, press the following keys:

```
F1, Ctrl-2
```

Pressing F1 with the Help pane open opens the help content in the IDE's Help mode which fills the full edit area. Ctrl+2 switches back to the edit mode; the Help pane is closed when you switch back. I tested this in Qt Creator 5.0.3.